# Vaadin/compass: URL paths from imported theme scss not compiled correctly

Tags: url, sass, themes, compass-sass, vaadin7

I'm trying to compile a modified version of the styles.scss from the Vaadin Dashboard theme with **compass**. Like most Vaadin themes, it imports the Vaadin Base theme:

```
@import "../base/base.scss";
```

In pre-compiled themes, URLs specified in base.scss have been updated to match the location of the Base theme relative to the theme importing with a prefix **../base/** . For example, a statement like

```
background: transparent url(tree/img/connector-collapse.png) no-repeat 2px -52px;
```

is updated to

```
background: transparent url(../base/tree/img/connector-collapse.png) no-repeat 2px -52px;
```

When compiling my modified Dashboard theme with compass, URLs specified in base.scss are not updated with the ../base prefix. I suspect this problem might be very common, but I've been searching for hours and my keywords have resulted mostly in other url-related problems.

Any suggestions would be most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using the com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler instead of compass.